# implementing use choise theme on entire application rather than calling settheme or recreate on every activity

Tags: android, android-layout, themes, android-theme

I have two different themes, I have to give this choice to the user to select the theme. but I have to call recreate() on every screen. is there any way to set the theme to entire application.

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
lateinit var currentTheme: String
lateinit var previousTheme: String
lateinit var sharedPref: SharedPreferences

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    if(this::currentTheme.isInitialized){
        previousTheme = currentTheme
        currentTheme = sharedPref.getString(KEY_CURRENT_THEME, LILAC_THEME)!!
    }else{
        currentTheme = sharedPref.getString(KEY_CURRENT_THEME, LILAC_THEME)!!

        previousTheme = currentTheme
    }
    setAppTheme(currentTheme)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if(this::currentTheme.isInitialized){
        previousTheme = currentTheme
        currentTheme = sharedPref.getString(KEY_CURRENT_THEME, LILAC_THEME)!!}
    if(currentTheme != previousTheme)
        recreate()
}

private fun setAppTheme(currentTheme: String) {
    when (currentTheme) {
        MINT_THEME -> setTheme(R.style.Theme_App_Mint)
        BLACK_THEME -> setTheme(R.style.Theme_App_Black)
        BLUE_THEME -> setTheme(R.style.Theme_App_Blue)
        else -> setTheme(R.style.Theme_App_Lilac)
    }
}
```

}

every activity is extended to this baseactiviy. in which i have to call recreate on onResume to check the difference of theme and to make the decision to change the theme.

Answer (score 0):

I just force restart of application after theme change with user prompt before the restart happens. This way I have to worry about theme load only in `onCreate()`.